Can not connect GitHub Copilot to my Visual Studio
In Visual Studio I am clicking in the right upper corner GitHub Copilot and then Add GitHub account to Visual Studio....

Then I log into my GitHub account and click Continue.

After that I am getting redirected to https://localhost:59144/ with the This site can’t be reached message.

So, as a result nothing changes in Visual Studio, particularly I am not getting logged into GitHub Copilot in Visual Studio. Is there a way to access GitHub Copilot through Visual Studio or is it supposed to work only with Visual Studio Code?

Try changing the browser, I had the same issue with edge, I tried with chrome and it worked. Might be an issue with cache, try clearing that as well

Worked also for me. Firefox gave me this problem. Microsoft Edge worked.

Handling Localhost Redirection:
The authorization process involves redirecting to a localhost address. If this address doesn't resolve, it might be due to HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) settings. To address this:

In Edge:

Type edge://net-internals/#hsts in the address bar.
In the "Delete domain security policies" section, enter localhost and click Delete.


In Chrome:

Navigate to chrome://net-internals/#hsts.
Under "Delete domain security policies," enter localhost and click Delete.


In Firefox:

Type about:config in the address bar and press Enter.
Search for network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist.
Set its value to false.



Clearing HSTS settings for localhost can resolve redirection issues during authentication.

typical microsoft, just bought copilot, can't connect in visual studio, vscode nor azure data studio (switched accounts)

Another option that worked for me was adding a GitHub account - the Copilot was automatically registered as well.

